# Search functionality for multiple fields using sql

Tags: sql, database

I have a table that holds user data. It looks something like this:

```
ID Name  Surname Age
1  Alice Moore   23
2  David Moore   45
```

If working with only one field, lets say `Name`, which I have to use for my search key then I could simply do something like this:

```
Select * from Users where Name Like '% Al %'
ORDER BY DIFFERENCE(Name , 'Al') desc;
```

and get the data for user 1.

If I want the search operation to take into account other fields too, lets say `Surname`, I am not sure how to proceed.

How would `order by` know what column to use in the end so I can return the list based on relevance.

Comment: Add some sample data (with at least one of those extra columns), and the expected result.

Comment: @jarlh thanks for the suggestion. Edit made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before anything I'd like to say that I'm not sure how advisable it would be following my solution below in tables with a considerable amount of data. It's simply something I came up that I think should work for your case.

**First try**

What you could do is order by the minimum `difference` of all columns of interest in each row.

```
SELECT FirstName, 
       LastName, 
(SELECT MIN(v) 
   FROM (VALUES (DIFFERENCE(FirstName , 'Al')), 
                (DIFFERENCE(LastName , 'Al'))) AS value(v)) as diff

FROM Users WHERE FirstName LIKE 'Al%' OR FirstName LIKE 'Al%'
ORDER BY diff DESC;
```

Try an interactive fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9b944/5).

**Second try**

Another option is ordering your result in a descending order of the difference of the concatenated string of all the rows of interest.

```
SELECT FirstName, 
       LastName 
FROM   Users 
WHERE  CONCAT (FirstName, LastName) LIKE 'Al%'
ORDER BY 
       DIFFERENCE(CONCAT (FirstName, LastName) , 'Al') DESC;
```

Try an interactive fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d0900/3).